# Java: How to deduct nested generic type

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have class:

```
public interface ObjectWithId<T> {
    T getId();

    void setId(T id);
}

public class BaseDBObject<T> implements ObjectWithId<T> {
    // Common fields:
    private T id;
    private String createdBy;
...
}
```

And one concrete:

```
public class ConstituentEntity extends BaseDBObject<Integer> {
...
}
```

Then I create some service, which say also take generic parameter one of `? extends BaseDBObject` and in some method should operate with `id` of appropriate type.
Now it implemented with double generics:

```
abstract public class BaseService<IdT,T extends BaseDBObject<IdT>> {
    public T getById(IdT id){
        return getDao().getById(id);
    }
}

public class ConstituentEntityService extends BaseService<Integer, ConstituentEntity>{
...
}
```

But look at last definition again. I known what `ConstituentEntity` already have `Integer` as their key holder, so it is seems ugly for me again provide that type for service.

I look some possibility to write next construction:

```
abstract public class BaseService<T extends BaseDBObject> {
    public T getById(??T.T?? id){
        return getDao().getById(id);
    }
}
```

In C++ we have `typename` and `typedef` for such cases with their complex but powerful metaprogramming possibilities.
Is something similar possible in Java?

Comment: Maybe not the best comment, but: often, Java generics are inescapably ugly. You just have to suck them up. I'd have done it exactly the same as your "double generics" way.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, it's not possible. If you have many services which use `Integer` as `T`, then you may define intermediate class:

```
public abstract class IntegerService<S extends BaseDBObject<Integer>> 
                                  extends BaseService<Integer, S>{
    ...
}
```

And use `public class ConstituentEntityService extends IntegerService<ConstituentEntity>`. But you will have to do this for every `T` type which might be inappropriate if there are many different types used as `T`.

Comment: It may be (ugly) workaround of problem. Beside there 2 generic types, it will hidden in next hierarchy. Meantyme it has several disadvantages. First (mentioned by you) - create intermediate class for any type. Second, it just classes for implementation and looks like garbage. And last, that number will be explode increased anywhere where it used (not only service need it, also validators, helpers and so on).

Comment: @Hubbitus, that's why I started my answer with "it's not possible". I don't like my solution either.